# Clearscript put Dictionary as function argument

Tags: c#, clearscript

I have JS code:

```
function on_save() {
    Service.AddTableRow([{id: 21194, value: "jjkk"}, {id: 1234, value: "Lala"}]);
    return true;
}
```

Into c# I do:

```
var engine = new V8ScriptEngine();
engine.AddHostObject("Service", scriptService);
engine.Execute(content);
result = engine.Script.on_save();
```

Into `scriptService` I have:

```
public void AddTableRow(Dictionary<string, object> values)
{
    //but there is invalid argument "values"
    //I also tried List<object> param type but result is the same
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public void AddTableRow(IList list) {
    foreach (ScriptObject item in list) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", item["id"], item["value"]);
    }
}
```

You can see this sample working [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJodWj).

**EDIT**: If you're using something older than ClearScript 6, you can do something like this instead:

```
public void AddTableRow(dynamic list) {
    int length = list.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        var item = list[i];
        Console.WriteLine("{0} → {1}", item.id, item.value);
    }
}
```

This technique is also demonstrated [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJodWj). Newer ClearScript versions support both.

Comment: No, error: `Error: The best overloaded method match for ScriptService.AddTableRow(System.Collections.IList)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: What are you passing to AddTableRow? My sample works with the JS above (in on_save). Also, what’s your ClearScript version?

Comment: I've added a link to a working .NET Fiddle in my answer.

Comment: I'm using ClearScript v5.4.1.0, and have error `Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ScriptObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Whoa, that's quite old; 5.5.3 is the first version available on NuGet. Anyway, see my updated answer above.

Comment: `'ScriptObject'` from what namespace?

Comment: https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Reference/html/T_Microsoft_ClearScript_ScriptObject.htm